# jQuery append html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 `p` elements as follows

```
<p id="booking-sum-start"><span id="booking-sum-start-new"><span id="booking-summary-start-date"><?php echo $booking->start_date;?></span></span></p>
<p id="booking-sum-end"><span id="booking-sum-end-new"><span id="booking-summary-end-date"><?php echo $booking->end_date;?></span></span></p>
```

I have a date picker to select dates and i'm showing the selected dates as above. My approach is every time a user selects a date range i'm removing `span` element with id `booking-summary-start-date` and `booking-summary-end-date` and updating the `span` using `.append` method of jquery as follows.

```
      let booking_start_date = document.getElementById("booking-summary-start-date");
      let booking_end_date = document.getElementById("booking-summary-end-date");

      booking_start_date.remove();
      booking_end_date.remove();

      let booking_start_date_container = document.getElementById("booking-sum-start-new");
      let booking_end_date_container = document.getElementById("booking-sum-end-new");

      booking_start_date_container.append(`<span id="booking-summary-start-date">${start_date}</span>`);
      booking_end_date_container.append(`<span id="booking-summary-end-date">${end_date}</span>`);
```

here the removing part works but when appending it appends a string of for ex: ${start_date} instead of a span element.

How can i append the span element instead of a string ?

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening. Also, mention if you are getting any errors in the console.

Comment: As you've tagged this [jquery], change `booking_end_date_container.append` to `$(booking_end_date_container).append` and it will work fine (though I recommend using either vanilla javascript *or* jquery to remove these confusions).  Example of the two: https://jsfiddle.net/oa7rne6h/

Comment: Your code works fine when `start_date` and `end_date` have a value.

Comment: The issue is that javascript .append() doesn't work like jquery .append() and, as you've tagged both, one can only assume you're getting them mixed up (or just simply not understanding how one works).  Javascript's .append("string") will append it as a literal while jquery's .append(html) will parse the html and append nodes as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `createElement()` and then `.appendChild()` if you want it to add a child node to the container span:

```
let start_span = document.createElement('span');
start_span.id = 'booking-summary-start-date';
start_span.innerText = start_date;
booking_start_date_container.appendChild(start_span);

let end_span = document.createElement('span');
end_span.id = 'booking-summary-end-date';
end_span.innerText = end_date;
booking_end_date_container.appendChild(end_span);
```

Here I have created a snippet to demonstrate how it works:

```js
let booking_start_date = document.getElementById("booking-summary-start-date");
let booking_end_date = document.getElementById("booking-summary-end-date");

booking_start_date.remove();
booking_end_date.remove();

let booking_start_date_container = document.getElementById("booking-sum-start-new");
let booking_end_date_container = document.getElementById("booking-sum-end-new");

let start_date = '123';
let end_date = '456';

let start_span = document.createElement('span');
start_span.id = 'booking-summary-start-date';
start_span.innerText = start_date;
booking_start_date_container.appendChild(start_span);

let end_span = document.createElement('span');
end_span.id = 'booking-summary-end-date';
end_span.innerText = end_date;
booking_end_date_container.appendChild(end_span);
```

```html
<p id="booking-sum-start"><span id="booking-sum-start-new"><span id="booking-summary-start-date"><?php echo $booking->start_date;?></span></span></p>
<p id="booking-sum-end"><span id="booking-sum-end-new"><span id="booking-summary-end-date"><?php echo $booking->end_date;?></span></span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.